# How to change the modified time of a wordpress post?

Tags: wordpress

We are able to make use of ajax to update our post_meta as we wanted. However, it does not change the modified_time of the post.

We depend on the get_modified_time to show users when the post was last updated. (The newer the better)

I have searched around, and I don't see anyone using this technique yet.

Does anyone have an answer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

I used wpdb::query() to do this:

```
global $wpdb;

//eg. time one year ago..
$time = time() - DAY_IN_SECONDS * 365;

$mysql_time_format= "Y-m-d H:i:s";

$post_modified = gmdate( $mysql_time_format, $time );

$post_modified_gmt = gmdate( $mysql_time_format, ( $time + get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) * HOUR_IN_SECONDS )  );

$post_id = /*the post id*/;

$wpdb->query("UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET post_modified = '{$post_modified}', post_modified_gmt = '{$post_modified_gmt}'  WHERE ID = {$post_id}" );
```

Note: You **can't** use `wp_update_post()` if you want to explicity set the modified date(s) on the post, because it calls [wp_insert_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/), which determines that the post exists and [sets the post_modified and post_modified variables](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3223) to the current date.

Comment: this answer is correct, the accepted one is misleading

Comment: It is good answer, but you can replace date generation with WP functions `current_time('mysql')` and `current_time('mysql', 1)`

Comment: ```$post_id = [the post id];``` post id doesn't work as an array, but beside that. Perfect.

Comment: Apologies, that wasn't meant to be an array, just shorthand for `your-id-here`. Updated post 

Answer (score 7):

Very simple in PHP, where `80` is the post number:

```
// update post_modified and post_modified_gmt `datetime` on a post
$update = array( 'ID' => 80 );
wp_update_post( $update );
```

Comment: It is **very slow** way, if you want speed, use direct DB query, it will be like 20x faster.

Comment: And it will also be unsafe, as it won't be using wp hooks etc. keep using the wp way if you don't want weird bugs, cache issues etc

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change for set of posts, better use [Query Loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) to get each post id.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have previously collected the post ID from your ajax request you can then update `post_modified` and `post_modified_gmt` using the regular `wp_update_post` function:

```
$date = current_time('mysql');
                        
wp_update_post(array(
                            
        'ID'                => $post_id,
        'post_modified'     => $date,
        'post_modified_gmt' => get_gmt_from_date($date),
));
```

**Resources**

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/

Comment: Hi Rafa, ended up here from low-quality answer review queue. Since you got more points on SO than me, you surely know code-only answers are not considered good. Would be great if you could add a couple words of explanation.

Comment: Hey @MikeSzyndel thanks for the heads up. Yes I will add some intro to the answer right away.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly better function:

```
/**
 * Updates the "last modified" time of a post in the WordPress database.
 *
 * @param int $postID The ID of the post to update.
 * @param int $time The Unix timestamp to set the post's "last modified" time to.
 *                  This value should be in seconds since the Unix epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC).
 * @return bool True if the update was successful, false otherwise.
 */
function changePostLastModifiedTime($postID, $time)
{
    global $wpdb;

    // Get the post object by ID
    $post = get_post($postID);

    // Return false if post not found
    if (!$post) {
        return false;
    }

    // Get the name of the posts table
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'posts';

    // Update the post_modified and post_modified_gmt fields in the database
    $result = $wpdb->update(
        $table_name,
        array(
            'post_modified' => gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time),
            'post_modified_gmt' => gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time)
        ),
        array('ID' => $postID)
    );

    // Return false if the update query fails
    if ($result === false) {
        return false;
    }

    // Set the post_modified and post_modified_gmt values in the post object
    $post->post_modified = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
    $post->post_modified_gmt = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);

    // Clear the post cache to ensure that the updated values are used
    clean_post_cache($postID);

    // Return true upon success
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the dateModified of a post in WordPress with code, you can use the following steps:

Get the post ID of the post you want to change the dateModified for.

Create a new PHP function that takes the post ID as an argument and updates the dateModified.

The function:

```
function change_post_modified_date($post_id) {
  $post = get_post($post_id);

  $post->post_modified = time();

  wp_update_post($post);
}
```

Add the function to your WordPress theme's functions.php file.

Call the function to change the dateModified of the post. For example, to change the dateModified of the post with ID 123, you would use the following code:

```
change_post_modified_date(123);
```